# How to query a connection only query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have an Excel file with a named range, named "getValues"

In Power Query created a connection only query with the following:

```
let
    Source       = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="getValues"]}[Content],
    PartID       = Source{0}[Column1],
    Query        = "SELECT Part, Color FROM myParts WHERE PartID = '"& PartID &"'",
    Target       = Sql.Database("myServer", "myDatabase", [Query=Query])
in
    Target
```

I loaded this as a Connection Only query, and renamed it to qGetData

Now, how do I do something like this:

```
let
    Source = qGetData
    Query  = "SELECT Part FROM Source WHERE Color = 'Red'
    Target = ????
in
    Target
```

I tried doing

```
let
    Source = qGetData
    Query  = "SELECT Part FROM Source WHERE Color = 'Red'
in
    Query
```

but it just returns the actual query string as plain text

Answer (score 0):

Since the query `qGetData` is a "Power Query Table" (not SQL table), you cannot use SQL statements for that. You should use [Power Query M formula language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/).

something like:

```
let
    Source = qGetData,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Color] = "Red")),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Part", "Color"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```